# How to push local Database to Github

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I used Entity Framework for creating and using database, I linked my local server with the project but when I push it to Github, my friend pulled and they got bug because they don't have the database that is stored in my computer. How can I fix this? I have to create a new database in my project or anything else to make it easier? I use Visual Studio 2022. Thanks guys so much

[image]

The connection is on my server so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: the dumb way is to export the database into an `sql` or `bak` file and `commit` the blob. the other way is to write [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) and execute the migration whenever changes is made on the migration files. you can then use [seeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) to populate the database as needed.